Reference to المحيط in Hadith as One of Allah's Names
In which Hadith is the term المحيط referenced as one of the names of Allah?

Note that the beautiful names are not only named or taken from hadith, but from Qur'an also some scholars, who consider المحيط considered the mentioning of this name/attribute in (2:19) and (11:92 as an evidence.
